# How do I build webpages that can communicate with iOS devices?

Tags: ios, web

I've got a pretty good handle on Objective C and my next step is to learn to build webpages that can communicate with iOS devices.

I want to be able to create text on the iPhone and push it to a webpage and vice versa.
I want to be able to push video and picture to the website and vice versa from the iPhone.
I want to be able to access SQL databases on a website as well as push data into an online SQL database from CoreData on the iPhone using SQL as persistent store.

Which languages, technologies and development environments do I need to get and learn?

Thanks.

-A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm just doing this myself :).

A lot of questions, but to keep it simple... I would recommend building REST based JSON web-services exposed from your website.  This seems to be the most commononly used method these days.  Hopefully you can keep it simple and not worry about authentication, but if you do you can always use some basic HTTP authentication.  Otherwise, if you want something more complex take a look at OAuth2 (http://oauth.net/2/).

For technologies, PHP seems to be the easiest to get up and running and you can find a ton of PHP REST/JSON web-service examples out there.

Comment: Great, I'm going to run down this rabbit trail. Thanks.